# How to i replace contents of one column with only part of another column in the same table?

Tags: sql, regex

I have columnA with /home/docs/test1 . I want the other column (columnB) to only be populated with only test1. I want to do this for the whole table.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What you have tried so far?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2013.

Comment: my query so fair is: update table set columnA = REPLACE(columnA, ColumnB, .... ) . I dont know to use regex on that column to get the desired part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reverse trick here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET columnB = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(columnA),
                                1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(columnA)) - 1));
```

If some of the paths might be only a single level, i.e. there is no path divider `/` present, *and* in that case you would want to retain the entire path, then you can slightly modify the above to the following:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET columnB = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', columnA) > 0
                   THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(columnA),
                                1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(columnA)) - 1))
                   ELSE columnA END;
```

Here is a demo showing that the above logic works:

### Demo

Comment: I found an easier way to it but thanks It 
UPDATE my TABLE
SET columnB = REPLACE(columnA,'/home/docs/','')

Comment: @udhkl But your solution is less flexible than mine, and will break if the path is anything but `home/docs/***`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need last tuple then above is fine. But if need Random then below query will help to make it split.

DECLARE @Var_xml XML

```
    SELECT @Var_xml = Cast('<root><x>'+ Replace('/home/docs/test1', '/', '</x><x>')+ '</x></root>' AS XML)

    SELECT DISTINCT f.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS tupple
    FROM @Var_xml.nodes('/root/x') f(x)
```